# Disable ios5 notification center pull down for webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, ios5

I have a web app which allows you to pull down a table of contents for navigation throughout a magazine-like document.

The new behaviour of the new notification center, pulled down from the center, is very annoying and destroys the flow of the user experience. Is there a way to disable notification center from working while using this webapp?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get access to the iOS API through a web app alone, so to answer your question short. No it is not possible.

Comment: dang. I was hoping there was a 'viewport' or 'apple-mobile-web-app' setting to disable the notification pull down while running a program which has a similar feature. I can think of three magazine/browsing/compiling apps/webapps which rely on being able to pull items down from the top that are going to have to find a new way to handle their features.